# Flutter app crash without error ( Android - Ios ) just in release mode

Tags: flutter, dart, crash, crashlytics

My App crash in just release mode ( never in debug mode ) .
and I can't know the reason of that , I'm trying to add firebase crashlytics but after the app crashing there is no crash session on firebase console , so can any one help me ?

```
Future<void> main() async {


  runZonedGuarded<Future<void>>(() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    // The following lines are the same as previously explained in "Handling uncaught errors"
    //  FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;
    FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) async {
      await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError(details);
      exit(0);
    };
    runApp(MyApp());
  }, (error, stack) => FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack));
}
```

Update :
In debug mode I got this exception randomly happen when click on text field or back button  :

> Choreographer(25563): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing
> too much work on its main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`. Then, run your app.

If that doesn't work try running in profile mode.

Comment: Flutter clean and flutter pub get not work for me

can you explain how will profile mode help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check whether you have added the below or not in AndroidManifest.xml incase you are using Google Ads?

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-6120620279244799~6424579957"/>
```